# php input handling: are there risks besides mail,queries and file handling?

Tags: php

I have been writing php for quite some time and never really thought about it until now but if i were to just use a raw post variable in an if statement does it have the slightest chance of being harmful? or is it only harmful in mail,mysql or file strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A string in itself is not harmful unless there's a bug in PHP.

Strings can be harmful if you make specific assumptions about the data and use it in sensitive processes without validating them. Think about values you insert in SQL statements, file names, fragments used in eval (which you should never use anyway)...

You could basically say that these strings are all executed or used in an execution in some way.
If you get input from a user, and use that input without validation in those situations, you're at risk.

Inside an if statement (I assume you're talking about a string comparison, like `if (userInput === 'whatever')`) this is not a problem at all. In this case, you're only comparing data and nothing gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are safe as long as you don't ever pass a user-set variable to exec(). The reason it is dangerous in mail,mysql,file string is because PHP can only pass data to/from these and all of those are "dumb", they do exactly what they are told to do. So if you tell them to do something dangerous they will. Same with XXS, if you take a user input and display it exactly to a page the user could add in JS or iframes or a whole slew of dangerous things into your site

Answer (score -1):

Don't trust any user generated data including url params, query params, post data, cookies and even request headers.

The most simple advice is: always filter input and sanitize output.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, trusting user input is never an option. It doesn't matter where it comes from; HTML forms, all HTTP requests and it's headers, cookies and what else you can think of.

If the data you are going to use is from user input then sanitize, validate, check and make sure that you get what you need and that it can't harm your application in any way.